# ASP.NET MVC - data validation for modal window doesn't work

Tags: validation, asp.net-core-mvc, modal-dialog

In my MVC application I have simple model for project:

```
public class Project
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MinLength(5, ErrorMessage = "Project name must have at leat 5 characters")]
    public string ProjectName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [MinLength(10, ErrorMessage = "Project description name must have at leat 10 characters")]
    public string ProjectDescription { get; set; }

    public ICollection<BugTrackerUser> Users { get; set; }

    public Project()
    {
        Users = new List<BugTrackerUser>();
    }
}
```

On the index page I have button that triggers bootstrap modal window. As a button, modal itself located in Index.chtml, but form that belongs to this model located in partial view _addProjectPartialView:

```
<form method="post" id="projectForm">
<div asp-validation-summary="All" class="text-danger"></div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="ProjectName">Project Name</label>
    <input asp-for="ProjectName" class="form-control" />
    <span asp-validation-for="ProjectName" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="ProjectDescription">Project Description</label>
    <input asp-for="ProjectDescription" class="form-control" />
    <span asp-validation-for="ProjectDescription" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
```

In HomeController I have this post method for adding new project:

```
    [HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public IActionResult AddProject(Project project)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        _repository.AddProject(project);
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
    return PartialView("_addProjectPartialView", project);
}
```

Logic of adding new project works fine, and I have all references that i need, jquery, jquery-validation and jquery-validation-unobtrusive, but I have problems with validation. Validation errors doesn't displays in my modal window. What can I try to solve this problem? I already read a bunch of tutorials, related questions etc, but it seems to me that there is no problems with code. I only have doubts with my return statement in AddProject method, should I return something else?

I solved this problem by removing partial view. Form that I Have in partial view and modal window I placed in Index.cshtml, also instead of asp.net tag helpers I use Html.BeginForm, and it works fine. Here is my modal:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="addProjectModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="addProjectModallLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content">
        @using (Html.BeginForm("AddProject", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
        {
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Project Information</h5>
                <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                @Html.HiddenFor(p => p.Id)
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(p => p.ProjectName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-3" })
                    <div class="col-9">
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(p => p.ProjectName, new { @class = "form-control" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(p => p.ProjectName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(p => p.ProjectDescription, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-3" })
                    <div class="col-9">
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(p => p.ProjectDescription, new { @class = "form-control" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(p => p.ProjectDescription, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>
                @*<partial name="_addProjectPartialView" />*@
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <div>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnSave">Save</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        }
    </div>
</div>
```

I also using ajax post method to add projects and render list of projects async on the client side:

```
<script type="text/javascript">$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#btnSave').click(function () {

        var projectData = $('#projectForm').serialize();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Home/AddProject",
            data: projectData,
            success: function () {
                window.location.href = "/Home/Index";
            }

        })

    })
})


$('#closeButton').click(function () {
    $('#addProjectModal').modal('hide');
})</script>
```

But I still want to understand how to solve this problem, because using partial views have some benefits

Comment: Hi @Ishootdice, where did you add the js reference? And how do you render the partial view to the modal content? Also, how do you send request to the `AddProject` method?

Comment: Hi @Rena, I have js references at _Layout.cshtml and validation js in _ValidationScriptsPartial.cshtml. I tried to move these references in different places many times. Validation itself working very well, but in case of modal window it fails. Partial view I rendered also in different ways, with Html.RenderPartial, with <partial> tag, and so on. I have no problems with this. Request to AddProject method I sent with help of ajax. Post request with ajax also works well and reload information async on client

Comment: @Rena I solved this problem when I removed my partial view and place all modal with form in one place(index page), and by using Html.BeginForm, it seems to me that bootstrap modal have some problems with rendering error messages right, because I already seen similar questions. But also many people don't have such problems. Validation should work fine, even with partial view and asp.net tag helpers, but for me it doesn't works and I don't know why...

Comment: @Rena I have edited my question, so you can see how my modal looks like and how I post my data with ajax

Comment: Hi @Ishootdice, did you add the client side validation related js or you just want the server side validation? If you add the client side validation related js in main page, it should work. If you just want the server side validation, you can see your `AddProject` method, you just return partial view but do not do anything in the ajax callback function. Actually I suggest you use client side validation because no matter the ModelState is valid or not, it always return correct response to the success function.

Comment: Hi @Rena, I use client side validation, and it doesn't works if I have partial view for modal window, but when I use all in one cshtml, I talk about button that triggers modal, modal itself and form with inputs for this modal, validation works fine. So I sure that there is all client side related js in my main, and it's not the case

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem here is , when you triggers the modal that modal doesn't have the references to (validator unobtrusive).
So try manually register this where you triggers the modal like this

```
$.validator.unobtrusive.parse("#idForModal");
```

Comment: I have tried to do this, but it doesn't help. I solve my problem when I remove ajax post method, now everything works fine. So I think that there is some problems with ajax